# Power BI: Merge Rows Where Column Values Match

Tags: database, powerbi, powerquery

I want to merge the rows of my table whenever the column values match. For instance, here is the table currently:

```
Commodity | Region | Unit  | 2007   | 2008  | 2009
 Corn |        US  |    $  |    10  | null  | null
 Corn |        US  |    $  |  null  | 20    | null
 Corn |        US  |    $  |  null  | null  | 30
```

I want it to look like:

```
 Corn |        US  |    $    |  10  | 20  | 30
```

I have found a resource online saying to first select columns Commodity, Region, Unit and unpivot the others, then to pivot the newly created attribute column and select the value column for my values. However, that just results in the same table as before.

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, please accept it so we can mark as solved

Answer (score 1):

One way in powerquery. Assumes that the grouping are on Commodity/Region/Unit and that the number of columns after that is dynamic

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
base = {"Commodity", "Region", "Unit"},
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source,base, {{"data", each 
    let #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(_, base, "Attribute", "Value")
    in Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
    , type table }}),
Columns=List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", Columns,Columns)
in #"Expanded data"
```

[image]